# Quit subsequent files opened with gvim *.c?

Tags: gvim, quit

If I use `gvim *.c` in a directory with multiple C files, gvim opens the next one once I close the one I am looking at.

The warning message given is `E173: n more files to edit`.

How do I quit all subsequent files? Meaning I don't want gvim to open any more files.

Answer (score 4):

When I tried the same thing, I got this error message:

```
E173: 3 more files to edit
```

I ran  `:help E173` and read

```
                        *E173*  >
 {number} more files to edit

You are trying to exit, while the last item in the argument list has not been
edited.  This protects you from accidentally exiting when you still have more
files to work on.  See |argument-list|.  If you do want to exit, just do it
again and it will work.
```

The command `:q!` worked for me.  So did running `:q` twice (like the help page indicated).

Comment: `:qa` should also work; the difference being that `:q!` will also quit on various other error conditions (like the buffer not being written), whereas `:qa` won't.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because the subsequent files were opened without having been actually loaded: In other words, you never switched to that buffer. So, a way of fixing this would be to cycle through all your files right as you open vim. Adding this to your .vimrc should work:

```
" do one full loop through each file given through the commandline
if argc() > 1
    for _ in range(argc() - 1)
      next
    endfor
    first
endif
```

Comment: Might be worth using `argc()` as the count and `:next` to iterate the arglist instead, since that's what inspires the error. Also, you could rewind things by finishing with `:rewind` (also `:first`) so that we still start with the first file. Note that this in general could heavily impact startup time. If using args: could also do `for _ in range(argc()-1) | next | endfor | first`, and ofc `argc()-1 == len(argv())-1`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have fixed the loop to reflect your recommendations.

Comment: might be worth adding `silent! next` and `silent! first`? Otherwise I get "Press ENTER or type command to continue" on startup.